# Removing blank space from the dictionary key name

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` with some key-value pairs stored in it. My problem is that in my dictionary, I have a blank space at the start of the key name, so for accessing the value, I have to use:

```
Pair[" Key"];
```

Is there any method where I can remove the starting whitespace, so I can access the value like:

```
Pair["Key"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trimming your string is enough. Besides that you can also write a custom key comparer for your dictionary instead of trimming your string everytime you add or get something to/from your dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(new Comparer());
dict.Add("aa ", 10);
int i = dict[" aa"];

public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Trim().Equals(y.Trim());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.Trim().GetHashCode();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have a `string`, you can remove leading and trailing whitespace with `key.Trim()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)).

If you want to trim all the keys in your dictionary, you can do this:

```
dictionary = dictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Trim(), x => x.Value);
```

This has room for failure, though, if you have 2 keys that will trim to the same value. For example, it is valid to have a dictionary with keys " key" and "key ", but if you trim them all, you'll get an `ArgumentException` because you'd be trying to add the same key twice ("key").

Comment: can also do this: dictionary = dictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Replace(" ",""), x => x.Value); to get rid of any blank spaces in your dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

Use [string.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method:

```
var key = " Key".Trim();
Pair[key];
```